# Rust Docker custom dependencies

Tags: docker, rust, rust-cargo

Im using `cargo-wharf` to build my Rust project.

Cargo.toml:

```ini
# syntax = denzp/cargo-wharf-frontend:v0.1.0-alpha.2
[package]
name = "project_name"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
dep1 = {path = "../dep1", version = "0.2.0"}
...


[package.metadata.wharf.builder]
image = "clux/muslrust:nightly-2019-09-28"
target = "x86_64-unknown-linux-musl"

[package.metadata.wharf.output]
image = "scratch"
user = "root"

entrypoint = ["/usr/local/bin/project_name"]

[[package.metadata.wharf.binary]]
name = "project_name"
destination = "/usr/local/bin/project_name"
```

---

When I run `docker build -f Cargo.toml . -t project_name`,
this error occurs:

```
[+] Building 5.2s (11/11) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Cargo.toml                                                                                                                                      0.0s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.38kB                                                                                                                                                    0.0s 
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                         0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                           0.0s 
 => resolve image config for docker.io/denzp/cargo-wharf-frontend:v0.1.0-alpha.2                                                                                                          3.3s 
 => CACHED docker-image://docker.io/denzp/cargo-wharf-frontend:v0.1.0-alpha.2@sha256:a57861317aa7ae8010927d6e000c9be523d3b78c2b42f3e5c281c8cc3328b1a0                                     0.0s 
 => Using build context                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s 
 => => transferring dockerfile: 6.41kB                                                                                                                                                    0.0s 
 => CACHED docker-image://docker.io/denzp/cargo-container-tools:v0.2.0-alpha.1                                                                                                            0.0s 
 => => resolve docker.io/denzp/cargo-container-tools:v0.2.0-alpha.1                                                                                                                       0.7s 
 => CACHED Collecting configuration metadata                                                                                                                                              0.0s 
 => Resolving builder image                                                                                                                                                               0.5s 
 => Using build context                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s 
 => => transferring context: 6.41kB                                                                                                                                                       0.0s 
 => CACHED docker-image://docker.io/clux/muslrust:nightly-2019-09-28@sha256:05cd14b73ae42a978d67a12e099eac8f6fe61daf2a963b7f401817a246ba4948                                              0.0s 
 => ERROR Evaluating the build plan                                                                                                                                                       0.3s 
------
 > Evaluating the build plan:
#11 0.259 error: failed to load source for a dependency on `dep1`
#11 0.259
#11 0.259 Caused by:
#11 0.259   Unable to update /dep1
#11 0.259
#11 0.259 Caused by:
#11 0.259   failed to read `/dep1/Cargo.toml`
#11 0.259
#11 0.259 Caused by:
#11 0.259   No such file or directory (os error 2)
#11 0.259 error: Child process failed
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to solve with frontend gateway.v0: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Unable to evaluate the Cargo build plan => caused by: Unable to read Cargo build plan => caused by: Unable to read the file => caused by: grpc-status: Unknown, grpc-message: "executor failed running [/usr/local/bin/cargo-build-plan --manifest-path /context/Cargo.toml --output /output/build-plan.json --target x86_64-unknown-linux-musl --release]: exit code: 1"
```

---

`dep1` is a custom package that is at the same level as `project_name`.

So it is `C:\Users\me\shared_folder\project_name\Cargo.toml`
and `C:\Users\me\shared_folder\dep1\Cargo.toml`

When running `cargo run` from `C:\Users\me\shared_folder\project_name\Cargo.toml`, everything just works fine.

I already tried:

- changing edition = "2018" as I read somewhere had no impact
- deleted Cargo.lock and target folder, also didn't work for me

Does anyone know how to get my program + custom dependencies running in docker?

Comment: `docker build -f Cargo.toml` seems odd to me does docker acceppt `Cargo.toml` files?

Comment: @cafce25 it is indeed. But with https://hub.docker.com/r/denzp/cargo-wharf-frontend is should usually work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm somewhat baffled that [this is possible](https://hub.docker.com/r/denzp/cargo-wharf-frontend), but the solution to your problem is easy:

- You'll need to include the entire `shared_folder` (which contains both `lib1` and `project_name`) as build context, i.e. your build context must be `..` not `.`. Otherwise, the dockerized builder has no way of accessing `lib1`.
- You'll need to specify where to find your `Cargo.toml` since it's not in the working directory of the builder anymore. You could do that by adding a workspace `Cargo.toml` to `shared_folder`, but I think that using `--build-arg manifest-path=…` is easier.

In summary:

```bash
buildx build -f Cargo.toml --build-arg manifest-path=project_name/Cargo.toml ..
```

Comment: D'aww, too bad this [won't work](https://github.com/denzp/cargo-wharf/issues/35) with rust 2021.

Comment: Thanks @caesar, this works - even though the rust version is what now stops me. So I got to watch out for an alternative. 
Do you know by any chance, what to do to solve the same issue in regular Dockerfile? I tried it before, but there also seemed to be a problem with the folder hierarchy.

Comment: Just the same way. Make sure the lib1 folder is accessible to the build (If in doubt, try a `FROM alpine COPY . . RUN find . && false` to see what's up), and pass `--manifest-path` on your `RUN cargo build` instruction (or just `WORKDIR …/project_name` into it).